# Issue with PHP variable

Tags: php

All,
I have the following query in PHP:

```
$music_choice = $_POST['music_choice'];
$qryupdate = "Update event_details set ".$music_choice."='$song_id' where user_id='$_SESSION[oml_user_id]'";
```

I'm basically trying to pass in the variable of the column that I'd like to update. I can't get it so that it displays the variable as the column name instead of the variable.

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: When you echo `$music_choice` or `$_POST['music_choice']` do you have a value? When you echo the value of `$qryupdate` do you get a valid query?  We're not seeing all of the code, so that's the only question I can ask.

Comment: `displays the variable as the column name instead of the variable` can you explain this  alittle better. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean `music_choice` is the column name?

Comment: See demo: http://codepad.org/RWMA5ftq What's wrong? Also please read: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sql+injection

Comment: Can you give the url of the site, I have some interesting $_POST['music_choice'] Values I would like to try (Read on SQL injection). Also, echo your variables before u use them.

Comment: @ItayMoav Ah so you are also a fan of the punkband "user_id=$myuserid; --"

Comment: @EugenRieck: Aren't they on tour with `id='0';DROP TABLE event_details;--` ?

Comment: @ItayMoav I didn't show the part with the mysql_real_escape_string but would that prevent the SQL injections?

Comment: @Madmartigan they wanted to, but turns out a clause in the mysql_query() - contract barred them from doing two acts on one evening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I undestand your question...

```
$music_choice = $_POST['music_choice'];
$qryupdate = "Update event_details set ".$music_choice."='$song_id' where user_id='".$_SESSION['oml_user_id']."'";
echo $qryupdate;
```

btw THIS IS NOT GOOD PROGRAMMING because you should escape your variables before insert them in a SQL query using function like http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php